# Flickering screen, despite different graphic cards

Tags: hardware-failure

I'm using debian linux (but that's probably irrelevant) and my screen has start flickering. Not much, you can only see it on a black screen with white text on, but there it's really annoying.

I've tried three different graphics cards since I thought there where an error on my graphic card.

The same issue appears on two of the graphics cards (beeing of different make and model and works fine on other computers) and the third card works just fine, except it makes my computer hang sometimes when returning from sleep mode, about once a day.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried with a different monitor?

Comment: No, but I've plugged in the monitor to an other computer where it doesn't show any problems.

Comment: Could it also be the cable (either power or video)?

Comment: possible, but when I connected the monitor to an other computer I used the same monitor cables. It's a VGA connected LCD monitor.

Comment: Those cables tend to wear out frequently. By jiggling the ends of the cable a little one can check if the cable is OK.